# Обновить БД SQLite у пользователей

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Вопрос в следующем: Есть приложение использующее готовую БД с одной таблицей. Сейчас нужно добавить в эту таблицу новые записи.

Как у пользователей, которые уже скачали приложение обновить БД, так чтобы их записи не стерлись, но в добавились те записи, которых у них не было?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно будет выполнить метод `onUpdate()`
Почитайте про него. У меня сработало.

Comment: Это я знаю, через него я уже кое-какие изменения сделал. Но хотелось бы услышать каков алгоритм действий в этом случае?

Comment: Мне помог этот ответ: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Comment: спасибо. буду разбираться

Comment: если я помог Вам с ответом, Вы можете отметить мой ответ(галочка с лева).